# Do we want both proprietary-code and closed-source tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Curiousdannii remarked in chat that we have both the tags [proprietary-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proprietary-code) and [closed-source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-source). Their use seems to be very similar. Should we have both, or can we merge them in to one?

An [NGram search over google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=open+source%2Cclosed+source%2Cproprietary+code%2Cproprietary+software&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copen%20source%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclosed%20source%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproprietary%20code%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproprietary%20software%3B%2Cc0) shows that proprietary code or proprietary software are far more used than closed source.

edit: Maybe throw in [proprietary](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proprietary) for good measure. There are only two uses (of which one is non-software)

Answer (score 6):

No, we don't need both. Make [closed-source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-source) a synonym of [proprietary-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proprietary-code)

Answer (score -2):

An alternative viewpoint, since I think "closed source" is more likely to be recognized than "proprietary code" - it's just more obvious:

No, we don't need both. Merge the two, and make [proprietary-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proprietary-code) a synonym of [closed-source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-source).

Comment: -1 because not all proprietary code is closed source, some is "source visible".